# How to find records where at least a single record among multiple records having same column values matches with other table but one or more aren't?

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema

I have tables

**Table_A**

| Rec_Id | Cust_Id | Act_Cp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | x |
| 2 | 11 | y |
| 2 | 12 | z |
| 3 | 13 | x |
| 3 | 14 | y |
| 3 | 15 | z |
| 4 | 16 | z |

**Table_B**

| sf_id | sf_detail |
| --- | --- |
| x | good |
| y | bad |

I want to find the records where at least one of the record of a `rec_id` is present in `table_B` but one or more aren't.
the condition is `act_cp = sf_id`

Somehow my expected output will be:

| rec_id | cust_id | act_cp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | z |
| 3 | 15 | z |

In the above output , I would not need the row

| rec_id | cust_id | act_cp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 16 | z |

because there is only a single record with `rec_id =4`

Also,it would be great,if joins are not used since I don't want any data from table_b just need to check. So , the query can use exists, not exists statement

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_a t1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SF_ID FROM table_b t2 WHERE t1.act_cp = t2.sf_id)
```

I tried doing:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table_A AS t1
 WHERE Rec_Id IN
       (SELECT Rec_Id FROM Table_B GROUP BY Rec_Id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
   AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT Sf_Id FROM Table_B AS t2 WHERE t1.Act_Cp = t2.Sf_Id)
```

But this will work only for the above data.

If table_A is changed to the below, the query will not work.

| Rec_Id | Cust_Id | Act_Cp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | x |
| 2 | 11 | y |
| 2 | 12 | z |
| 3 | 13 | x |
| 3 | 14 | y |
| 3 | 15 | z |
| 4 | 16 | z |
| 5 | 17 | z |
| 5 | 18 | z |
| 5 | 19 | z |

I would like to make adjustments that at least a single record from multiple rec_id should match so the output would be similar to the previous one.

| rec_id | cust_id | act_cp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | z |
| 3 | 15 | z |

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Do you just want to get only one row for a specific rec_id? If yes what is the condition for that single row?

Comment: FROM TABLE a, I just removed the data which has count(rec_id)>1, trying it with

Comment: Why have you added the MySQL and T-SQL Tags? T-SQL is used by SQL Server, SyBase, Azure Synapse, among others. It is *not* used by MySQL. I have gone ahead, and removed the conflicting tags again, as we're effectively in the same position as before @a_horse_with_no_name  removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might need is an outer join along with a window function to count the occurence of the matching whenever grouped by `Rec_Id` column such as

```
WITH ab AS
(  
 SELECT a.*, b.*,
        SUM( CASE WHEN sf_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
             OVER ( PARTITION BY Rec_Id ) AS cnt
   FROM a
   LEFT JOIN b
     ON act_cp = sf_id
)  
SELECT Rec_Id,Cust_Id,Act_Cp
  FROM ab
 WHERE sf_id IS NULL   
   AND cnt > 0
```

<kbd>[Demo on MySQL DB](https://dbfiddle.uk/MFRuhIp4)</kbd>

Comment: why you are using sum? Invalid argument types for function 'SUM': (BOOLEAN), but it works in demo. not on snowflake

Comment: i was working with snowflake sql

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you need to get records that act_cp is not equal to "x" and "y" but "z" only. So remove any `rec_id`'s that have x-y in any row.

First, I would pick `rec_id`'s that include x and y's.

```
SELECT rec_id, cust_id
  FROM table_a
 WHERE act_cp IN (SELECT sf_id FROM table_b)
```

This will return:

| Rec_Id | Cust_Id | Act_Cp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | x |
| 2 | 11 | y |
| 2 | 12 | z |
| 3 | 13 | x |
| 3 | 14 | y |
| 3 | 15 | z |

Now time to get the remaining row that you requested

```
SELECT rec_id, cust_id, act_cp
  FROM table_a
 WHERE rec_id NOT IN
       (SELECT rec_id
          FROM table_a
         WHERE act_cp IN (SELECT sf_id FROM table_b));
```

I assume this is a long way but you get the results. The less expensive method is to use left joins - I know you stated "no joins" but it might be good for future reference

```
SELECT a.rec_id, a.cust_id, a.act_cp
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN table_b b
    ON a.act_cp = b.sf_id
 WHERE act_cp IS NULL;
```

So with this, you still won't return any data from table b and get your requested data.